# Typescript/JavaScript - Why does my promise run through after I'll resolved?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have this function:

```
export async function promisePlay(example: someInterface): Promise<string> {
    const data = await fetch(example.url)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       resolve("Lets test this")

       console.log("This point shouldnt be reached");
    })
}
```

When I run this I'm seeing the text `This point shouldnt be reached` in the console output. What I want (and thought) was that the `resolve()` should return and stop from running further.

Could someone please tell me what I'm fundamentally misunderstanding and how to correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Get someone else to ratify this but I suppose, if you await promisePlay(). then you can guarantee the code before (resolve) has been executed, however that's not to say it won't continue executing? if there's code after the resolve?

Comment: Because a `resolve()` call is not a `return` statement. If you want to `return` from the function, explicitly write that.

Comment: @Bergi - so you're saying I don't need to do `resolve()` just `return 'someString'`?

Comment: the returned value (by the executor function) is not received by any "client". The only use for `return` in the executor function, is just to end the function's execution.

Comment: No, it won't work. Instead, write `resolve(...); return` or just `return resolve(...)`

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should write `resolve('someString'); return;` if you want the code after that to become unreachable. A resolve call does not return from the function, it's unclear why you did expect that.

Comment: Btw why are you using `new Promise` at all in here?

Comment: Well if you think about it, its a promise, so each path through the logic should either result in a resolve() or a reject(), as someone said its good practice to ensure this happens in one place, but in theory you can do what you like, if your promise has paths through it which don't lead to a resolve, or reject, then your promise will be awaited for ever because its state will never reach reject or resolved. But the unfulfilled state

Comment: Is this function returning an promise that resolves another promise?

Comment: Why was this question voted down, this is very interesting behaviour from JS, Typescript, and as with interesting behaviour we seek reasons why

Comment: `resolve()` is JUST a function call (that happens to resolve the promise).  It doesn't stop execution of the current function.  That continues until you `return` or reach the end of the function body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolve` is a function in a variable.

You are calling the resolve function and passing the return value of the promise as the parameter.

However, that does not stop execution or break out.

If you want to exit the function, you must use `return;`.

Calling `resolve` does stop the pending await command of wherever you called the original function.

Whatever you value you pass to return will not be passed to the variable that resolves the promise and it will not stop the pending promise in the await command.

```
function test(yourWord) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
        // This will allow the command 
        // let res = await test("hello");
        // to continue executing. It will stop executing on that line
        // unless you call resolve or reject
        resolve("you said: " + yourWord);

        // this will continue to execute 
        console.log("I'm still alive");

        // this string return value will be ignored
        return "blah blah";

        // this will not be executed since the function has returned
        console.log("I'm dead");
    });
}

(async () => 
{
    // this will pause execution until resolve or reject is called and 
    // whatever value is passed into resolve() will be assigned to res
    let res = await test("hello");

    // this will echo out "you said hello"
    console.log("res: " + res);
})();
```

Comment: So if I have some conditional statement in there, I'd need multiple `resolve('someString');` followed by `return;`?

Comment: I would recommend having one resolve and one return and the value you want passed to the await to be in a variable set in the conditions statements and then passed as resolve(yourValue);.

Comment: return should not be the problem here, op is asking something else.

Comment: @AkshayBande he is asking why the function doesn't stop executing after calling resolve

Comment: Thanks @John - so to confirm what your saying, `resolve('someString')` just sets what will be returned. However using `return` actually stops further execution?

Comment: Yes, but op has mentioned that he thought after resolve promise won't execute, the answer should be specific to promise concepts. Your answer specifies normal function behavior in return statements.

Comment: So if I did `return resolve('someString`)`, I guess I kill 2 birds with one stone?

Comment: It would technically work, but you shouldn't do that since its illogical and serves no purpose but to confuse yourself and anyone who reads it. Since calling resolve returns `undefined` and you're returning `undefined` needlessly.

If you want to short hand it. Simply have resolve() be the last line of code in your function and then you wouldn't need to explicitly return.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had a conditional in the code, so was thinking have multiple points of resolve, however rethinking about it, probably not best code design. I'll refactor to only have one resolve at the end as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the resolve

```
  export async function promisePlay(example: someInterface): Promise<string> {
  const data = await fetch(example.url)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   return resolve("Lets test this")

   console.log("This point shouldnt be reached");
  })
  }
```

Comment: return should not be the problem here, op is asking something else.

Answer (score 0):

Promise body is synchronous, when you resolve the promise, it won't return(stop executing further statements).

I think you are confused between promises resolve and returning from them.

Consider below example,

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("inside promise");
  resolve("promise resolved");
  console.log("after resolving");
}).then(val => console.log(val));
```

In the above snippet, the console will print `inside promise` then `after removing`. It means it will execute all the statement in the promise first then it will wait for the promise to resolve. If you don't want to execute any statement further resolve, you can add return resolve in the function, cause its a normal function anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

A JS promise has [3 states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) initial, fulfilled and rejected.

When awaiting a promise, the code waits for the state to change from `initial` to either `rejected` or `resolved` before execution continues.

When you await your `promisePlay()` function, execution will continue after the await as soon as `reject()` or `resolve()` is called.

Your case is special because you have code `after` you have `resolved()` within your promise.

It appears that during some experimentation of my own, it appears the JS engine waits until all the code is executed after the `resolve()`, I suppose its a bad idea to rely on this behaviour, as other answers suggest perhaps you should be `return` the `result` you want within in the `resolve`